# Views overlapping in VStack

Tags: ios, swiftui, vstack, geometryreader, swiftui-scrollview

I have some data that will be loaded from a server and in the mean time I want to show a shimmer placeholder view.

To achieve the shimmer effect, I've created the following:

```
struct ShimmerEffectBox: View {
    @State private var startPoint: UnitPoint = .init(x: -1.8, y: -1.2)
    @State private var endPoint: UnitPoint = .init(x: 0, y: -0.2)
    
    private var gradientColors = [
        Color(uiColor: .systemGray5),
        Color(uiColor: .systemGray6),
        Color(uiColor: .systemGray5)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        LinearGradient(colors: gradientColors,
                       startPoint: startPoint,
                       endPoint: endPoint)
            .onAppear {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2)
                    .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                        startPoint = .init(x: 1, y: 1)
                        endPoint = .init(x: 2.2, y: 2.2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

The shimmer works fine and nothing needs to be looked at here.

I then create a `ScrollView` with some data and my placeholder views, however, for some reason the views are overlapping, this is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("Title")
                .font(.system(size: 20))
                .bold()
            
            ForEach(1...5, id: \.self) { _ in
                placeholderView
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var placeholderView: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                ShimmerEffectBox()
                    .frame(width: proxy.size.width / 2, height: 18)
                    .cornerRadius(4)
                
                ShimmerEffectBox()
                    .frame(height: 16)
                    .cornerRadius(4)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .padding(.bottom, 24)
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me the following result:

[image: VStack SwiftUI overlapping views]

I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong with the geometry reader, so I added the padding to the geometry reader

```
private var placeholderView: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
            ShimmerEffectBox()
                .frame(width: proxy.size.width / 2, height: 18)
                .cornerRadius(4)
            
            ShimmerEffectBox()
                .frame(height: 16)
                .cornerRadius(4)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    }
    .padding(.bottom, 24)
}
```

[image: SwiftUI VStack Overlapping]

This is better, however, the padding is definitely not 24.

My goal is:

- I want 4 placeholder views (this is achieved by the loop - no issues)
- each placeholder view should have 2 shimmer views. One shimmer view is full width and one is half (this also works - no issues)
- I want a padding of 24 between each shimmer view - this doesn't work

Not sure if I'm using geometry reader wrong or specifying the padding / spacing at the wrong place.

Comment: Also, before you reinvent the wheel, you could consider SwiftUIks inbuilt placeholder https://www.swiftbysundell.com/tips/swiftui-automatic-placeholders/

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 - it's a good suggestion which I started out with, however, I wanted something that I could animate, which might be possible still with redacted but it did seem like I did need to do some work to make it happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is happening because the `GeometryReader` is inside a `ScrollView`, which stops it from being as greedy as usual. Consequently, the height of the `GeometryReader` is very small.

Since you know the height of the `ShimmerEffectBox` (because you are setting it using `.frame`), you could fix the problem by setting a fixed height on the `GeometryReader` too:

```swift
GeometryReader { proxy in
    // content as before
}
.frame(height: 38)
```

However, it looks like you only need the `GeometryReader` to find the screen width, which you are dividing by two. The same result can be achieved by using an `HStack` that contains two views with `maxWidth: .infinity`. So you could also fix like this:

```swift
private var placeholderView: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ShimmerEffectBox()
                .frame(height: 18)
                .cornerRadius(4)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            Color.clear
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
        ShimmerEffectBox()
            .frame(height: 16)
            .cornerRadius(4)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
    .padding(.bottom, 24)
}
```

[image: Animation]

If you want to fine-tune the spacing between the content of the `ScrollView` then you might want to use a `VStack` as the top-level container inside the `ScrollView`. Then you can control the spacing of the `VStack`:

```swift
ScrollView {
    VStack(spacing: 0) { // or spacing: 24
        // content as before
    }
}
```

At the moment, the `ScrollView` is adding a bit of vertical space between each of the subviews it contains, which you might not be expecting.